# openhtmltopdf c# - page breaks not working and not creating new page in the PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, openhtmltopdf

I am using [OpenHtmltoPDF](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf) and its generating PDF files

The problem that I have is, it is not creating new pages

I tried including the below html, but they didn't work

```
<div style = 'display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;'></div>

<div style='display:block;page-break-before:always;'></div>
```

The same code however creates new page in this sandbox site they have

https://sandbox.openhtmltopdf.com/

Answer (score 1):

try to use the same [code](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/149)
. You need create "div" before your page break, I think this is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused two rendering utilities. The library that you use is [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf) (created by vilppu for .NET), whereas the sandbox page is created for [OpenHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) (created by danfickle for Java).

I don't know if .NET library supports `page-break-after` etc, but I know the Java one does.